# Using javascript to load new HTML segment inside page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, frames

I know this is a problem I could solve with a huge list in "innerHTML", but there's got to be a better way.
I'm making a webpage with a "search" and "browse" section, both are big buttons at the top of the index page.  I have search.html and browse.html, but I want their contents to load in my "main" div on the index page rather than open their own pages.  I should be able to quickly click between "search" and "browse" and have their different pages load back and forth inside the index page.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I was trying a solution with frames before, but it wasn't working for me.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: i cant stand those `big buttons`

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabs or something like that: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Most JavaScript AJAX libraries such as [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) have this built-in - in case of jQuery the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

However keep in mind, "tricks" like this destroys the browser usability for your users (broken back button, not possible to set bookmarks, etc.). It's possible to work around, but that makes extra work.